# Asking for help understanding an answer from five years ago

Tags: discussion

I've been struggling to understand the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8337300/522385). Unfortunately it was asked and answered five years ago. What's the protocol in this situation, where I need to ask follow-up questions and generally get more guidance and hand-holding than the original contributors obviously needed? (And where, possibly, there are now better solutions.)

Comment: You can ask OP for clarification in the comments.

Comment: Just check the [user's profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/147192/matthieu-m) and see when they were last active (_"Last seen 1 hour ago"_ as of this comment). They should be around to respond a comment on their answer.

Comment: Any "I need more hand holding" comment is not going to work and should not be attempted.  You can only comment with a very targeted question that can fit a comment and you are clearly not there yet.  Just ask your own question.  Be sure to look at a logging library first, at least log4cpp

Comment: At first I totally thought this was about a 5 year-old's answer.

Comment: Four years would be more fitting. Approximately 4 3 / 12 = 4 1/4 years.

Comment: @Chap LOL, well my kids understand smart phone interfaces better than I

Comment: @Don'tPanic: There aren't any of those. ;)

Comment: @LorenRogers I thought it was like an Explain Like I'm 5 kind of thing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the question that you have, you could do two things :

1. If all you need is some clarification, then it would be easy to drop a comment on the original post (or one of its answers) asking for clarification.
2. If option 1 doesn't work or if your question isn't a simple clarification, then you could create a new question and point to the old one as a reference.

Comment: Sounds like #2 is the way to go. (I'll also look at log4cpp.)

Comment: FWIW, I've written http://stackoverflow.com/q/36044897/522385

Answer (score 12):

You can ask OP for a clarification in the comments. If the answer is long and very detailed, try to avoid general questions like: "I don't get the solution, please explain it". Being more specific will make it easier for OP to explain the parts that you didn't get.

If that didn't work, you can ask a new question while linking to the one you don't get. But again, writing a good question will make the difference. Trying to demonstrate what parts you do understand and what parts you don't will help you getting a better explanation.

Comment: *But again, writing a good question will make the difference* -> Very important